# How to create mysql table entry on form submission in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter-3

I just need to insert data to table on form submission with the entered inputs.

my Controller,

```
function create_wish() {
    $data = array(
    'user_name' => $this->input->post('uname'),
    'user_email' => $this->input->post('uemail'),
    'user_message' => $this->input->post('umessage')
    );
    $this->model_wishes->createWish($data);
}
```

model,

```
function createWish($data) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO wishes (user_name, user_email, user_wish) VALUES (".$data.user_name.", ".$data.user_email.", ".$data.user_message.")";
        $this->db->query($sql);
        echo $this->db->affected_rows();
    }
```

view,

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url() . "index.php/Welcome/create_wish"?>">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="post-name">Name</label>
                            <input autocomplete='name' type="text" class="form-control" id="uname" name="uname" required />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="post-email">Email</label>
                            <input autocomplete='email' type="email" class="form-control" id="uemail" name="uemail" required/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-12 margin-b-2">
                            <label for="post-message">Message</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control" id="umessage" rows="5" name="umessage"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-12 text-left mb-0">
                            <button id="btn-create" type="submit" class="button-medium btn btn-default fill-btn">Post Wish</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Ajax,

```
$(document).ready(function () {

            $('form').submit(function (event) {

                var formData = {
                    'user_name': $('input[name=uname]').val(),
                    'user_email': $('input[name=uemail]').val(),
                    'user_wish': $('input[name=umessage]').val()
                };

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'http://localhost/CodeIgniterProj/index.php/create_wish',
                    data: formData,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    encode: true
                })
                        .done(function (data) {
                            console.log(data);
                        });
                event.preventDefault();
            });

        });
```

execution of above codes displays an error in console

```
POST http://localhost/CodeIgniterProj/index.php/create_wish 404 (Not Found)
XHR failed loading: POST "http://localhost/CodeIgniterProj/sender.php".
```

I tried to fix this and failed. Someone please let me know how to fix this issue, help me on this.

Comment: u r not calling `sender.php`  anywhere in this code it seems u r using ajax the error must be there

Comment: show your ajax code also

Comment: @pradeep added please check

Answer (score 0):

Your URL is missing the controller segment 
you should call `index.php/[controller]/[method]`. Regarding the sender.php i cannot see any call to it. Maybe there are other forms in the markup.

Besides that, the model will not work as expected. Since you are dealing with an array you should change:

```
... VALUES (".$data.user_name.", ...)
```

to

```
...(VALUES (".$data["user_name"].", ...)
```

If you don't want to use the active record class, you should escape the values in your query.

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html#escaping-queries

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use `site_url` in your ajax url , should be like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('form').submit(function (event) {
        var formData = $(this).serialize();

        alert(formData);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '<?=site_url('Welcome/create_wish');?>',
            data: formData,
            dataType: 'json',
        }).done(function (data) {
              console.log(data.id);
        });
        event.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

Your  controller should be like this :

```
function create_wish() {
    $data = array(
    'user_name' => $this->input->post('uname'),
    'user_email' => $this->input->post('uemail'),
    'user_message' => $this->input->post('umessage')
    );

    $insert_id = $this->model_wishes->createWish($data);
    if($insert_id)
    {
        $response = array('status' => 'success');
    }
    else
    {
       $response = array('status' => 'error');
    }

    echo json_encode($response);
    exit;
}
```

*Your model method `createWish` should be like this ;*

```
function createWish($data) 
{
    $this->db->insert('wishes', $data);
    return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

Comment: sir , please check my answer here too, if it helps you pls check my answer as green and do upvote also